# flat unordered list and tuples with implicit order lisp

Tags: list, data-structures, lisp, common-lisp

Is there a function in Lisp that works the same way as `assoc` works with association lists, but for flat, ordered lists and a set of tuples with an implicit ordering?  For instance, I have the a flat, unordered list and a lookup function:

```
(defparameter *data2* '((alf age 55 year 2 course lisp)
                        (sue age 22 year 3 course java)
                        (ralf age 16 year 1 course lisp)
                        (alf age 8 year 2 course lisp)))

(defun lookup (name course data)
  (cdr (assoc name (cdr (assoc course data)))))
```

such that when called, the `lookup` function is like:

```
(lookup 'alf 'course *data*) ==> get lisp
```

Now, with "tuples with implicit order" (i.e., lists of values where the values are always in the same order):

```
(defparameter *data3* '((alf 55 lisp 2)
                        (sue 22 java 3)
                        (ralf 16 lisp 1)
                        (alf 8 lisp 2)))
```

Are there any functions that work the same way as `assoc` for association lists, but for flat unordered lists and tuples with implicit order?

Comment: Your example function `LOOKUP` does not work.

Comment: I see that you've already accepted an answer, but I would point out that the first question about lists of the form `(key1 val1 key2 val2 ...)` has an answer in Common Lisp's _property lists_.  The second question, about list-based data structures, has some answers in `defstruct`, which can create those kind of structures for you and provide convenient accessors.  I've written about them in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20110923/1281433).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you fully; something like this?

```
(defun lookup (name attr data)
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (cadr (member attr x)))
          (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (eq name (car x))) data)))
```

then

```
? (lookup 'alf 'course *data2*)
(LISP LISP)
? (lookup 'alf 'age *data2*)
(55 8)
?(lookup 'ralf 'year *data2*) 
(1)
```

For your other example:

```
(defun lookup (name attr data)
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (nth attr x))
          (remove-if-not (lambda (x) (eq name (car x))) data)))
```

then

```
(lookup 'alf 2 *data3*)
(lookup 'alf 1 *data3*)
(lookup 'ralf 3 *data3*)
```

Comment: Yes that is working pefectly with flat unordered lists, do you know how it can be done with implicit ordered tuples like data3 thanks

Comment: @user3005313 You can access the values in a list (i.e., a tuple) if you do a bit of preparation using `defstruct`.  `defstruct` can automatically define, e.g., `person-name`, `person-age`, `person-year`, etc., functions for you, and this can make your task much easier.  I added an answer that shows how.

Comment: @uselpa Also note that you can make that `remove-if-not` a bit cleaner with `(remove name data :key 'car :test-not 'eq)` or `(remove name data :key 'car :test (complement 'eq))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER 63 > (mapcar (lambda (plist)
                       (getf (rest plist) 'course))
                     (remove 'alf *data2*
                             :test-not #'eql
                             :key #'first))
(LISP LISP)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this answer.  First, if you're trying to access values from a list of the form `(key1 value1 key2 value …)`, then should know that there's a special name for lists like that;  they're called property lists, and Common Lisp includes some functions for working with them.  Second, if you don't want the lists of have the keys in them, you can get a lot of what you want by using `defstruct` with `:type list`.  It will define the necessary functions you need in order to work with these implicit structures.

### Property Lists

Some of the other answers have described how you can do this, and [Rainer Joswig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20105674/1281433) uses the function `getf`, but none have made explicit that there's a name for this kind of structure, the [*property list*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#property_list):

> **property list** *n*. 1. a *list* containing an even number of *elements* that
>   are alternating *names* (sometimes called *indicators* or *keys*) and *values*
>   (sometimes called *properties*). When there is more than one *name* and
>   *value* pair with the *identical* *name* in a *property list*, the first such
>   pair determines the *property*. 2. (of a *symbol*) the component of the
>   *symbol* containing a *property list*.

Your *data2* variable is a association list mapping the names `alf`, `sue`, etc., to the property lists `(age 55 year 2 …)`, `(age 22 year 3 …)`, etc.:

```
(defparameter *data2* '((alf age 55 year 2 course lisp)
                        (sue age 22 year 3 course java)
                        (ralf age 16 year 1 course lisp)
                        (alf age 8 year 2 course lisp)
                        ))
```

Where you want

```
(lookup 'alf 'course *data2*)
;=> lisp
```

you can use [`assoc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm) to get `alf`'s property list

```
(cdr (assoc 'alf *data2*))
;=> (age 55 year 2 course lisp)
```

and then [`getf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_getf.htm) to retrieve the course:

```
(getf (cdr (assoc 'alf *data2*)) 'course)
;=> lisp
```

`getf` can also be provided a default value for the case that there's no value in the list:

```
(getf (cdr (assoc 'alf *data2*)) 'favorite-color 'blue)
;=> blue
```

You can also use `setf` with `getf`:

```
(setf (getf (cdr (assoc 'alf *data2*)) 'course) 'scheme)
;=> scheme

*data2*
;=> ((alf age 55 year 2 course scheme)
;    (sue age 22 year 3 course java)
;    (ralf age 16 year 1 course lisp)
;    (alf age 8 year 2 course lisp))
```

*Note: since the value of `*data2*` was a literal produced by `quote`, the consequences of modifying it are technically undefined.  It will probably work in this case, but in general, don't modify literal data.*

### Defstruct with `:type list`

In common Lisp, you can define simple record types using [`defstruct`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defstr.htm).  By default, these create structures that are probably pretty memory efficient (low storage overhead, and constant time slot access).  However, you can specify a `:type list` option to `defstruct` that makes the structures be implemented in terms of lists.  For instance:

```
(defstruct (person (:type list))
  name
  age
  course
  year)
```

This defines a number of functions for you automatically.  For instance, one is `make-person`:

```
(make-person :name 'alf
             :age 55
             :year 2
             :course 'lisp)
;=> (alf 55 lisp 2)
```

The others are accessors.  These are (by default) prefixed with the name of the structure and a hyphen.  For instance, `person-age` and `person-year` retrieve the values of the age and year slots from a person.  These are really just aliases to the corresponding list functions `second` and `third`), so they work on lists that have the correct structure, even if they weren't created with `make-person`:

```
(person-age (make-person :name 'alf :age 55 :year 2 :course 'lisp))
;=> 55

(person-year '(alf 55 lisp 2))
;=> 2
```

Now you can use `find` to retrieve a person by name from your `*data3*` (note that you changed the order of course and year from `*data2*` to `*data3*`):

```
(defparameter *data3* '((alf 55 lisp 2)
                        (sue 22 java 3)
                        (ralf 16 lisp 1)
                        (alf 8 lisp 2)))

(find 'sue *data3* :key 'person-name)
;=> (sue 22 java 3)
```

and you can use the `person-*` functions to get the values:

```
(person-year (find 'sue *data3* :key 'person-name))
;=> 3
```

Of course, to do something like

```
(lookup 'alf 'course *data*)
```

you'll somehow need to know that the symbol `course` corresponds to the function `person-course`.  You could create a hash table or another association or property list to keep track of these.  Another, somewhat kludgy, way to do this, is to take the symbol name of `course` which is `"COURSE"`, concatenate `"PERSON-"` with it, and intern it to get the symbol `person-course`, which you can then `funcall` with the person.  That is:

```
(defun lookup (name slot-name data)
  (funcall (intern (concatenate 'string "PERSON-" (symbol-name slot-name)))
           (find name data :key 'person-name)))

(lookup 'alf 'course *data3*)
;=> lisp
```

*Note: to make the symbol interning more robust, we should really be sure to intern the symbol into the package where accessor names are interned, and to account for readable case issues. We might, for instance, do `(intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name '#:person-) (symbol-name slot-name)) (symbol-package 'make-person))`.  (There are better ways to get the package, of course.)*